# ObjectInputStream throws EOFexception when reading a file with an object in it

Tags: java, serialization, objectinputstream, eofexception

Im trying to read a `Treemap` from a file. I know that there is a `TreeMap` serialized in the file, my problem is that OIS throws an `EOFexception` on that file.

```
public class FileDBMapApi {

    private FileOutputStream OutPutter;
    private FileInputStream Inputter;
    private ObjectInputStream InputStream;
    private ObjectOutputStream OutputStream;
    private NavigableMap<Integer, Object> data;
    private File currentFile;
    private int autoIncrement;

    /**
     * @param dataFile is the file to use as a database
     */
    public FileDBMapApi(String dataFile) {
        String fullPath = "data/" + dataFile;
        currentFile = new File(fullPath);
    }

    // initialiserar databasen
    public void init() {
        // checkar om filen existerar och isåfall assignar inputter och outputter till filen
        System.out.println(currentFile.exists() && !currentFile.isDirectory());
        if (currentFile.exists() && !currentFile.isDirectory()) {
            try {
                OutPutter = new FileOutputStream(currentFile);
                OutPutter.flush();
                Inputter = new FileInputStream(currentFile);
                OutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(OutPutter);
                OutputStream.flush();
                InputStream = new ObjectInputStream(Inputter);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            // annars så skapar den filen och assignar det istället
            try {
                boolean temp1 = currentFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                boolean temp2 = currentFile.createNewFile();
                if (temp2) {
                    OutPutter = new FileOutputStream(currentFile);
                    Inputter = new FileInputStream(currentFile);
                    OutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(OutPutter);
                    InputStream = new ObjectInputStream(Inputter);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // läser in hashmapen från filen
        this.convertData();
    }

    public void write() {
        try {
            PrintWriter n = new PrintWriter(currentFile);
            n.close();
            OutputStream.writeObject(data);
            OutputStream.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public int add(Object o) {
        int id = autoIncrement;
        data.put(autoIncrement, o);
        autoIncrement++;
        return id;
    }

    public Object get(int i) {
        return data.get(i);
    }

    public void close() {
        try {
            OutPutter.close();
            Inputter.close();
            InputStream.close();
            OutputStream.flush();
            OutputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // returnar data
    public NavigableMap<Integer, Object> getAll() {
        return data;
    }

    public long getFileSize() {
        return currentFile.length();
    }

    // tar data från en fil och sätter in det till en hashmap
    private void convertData() {
        try {
            if (InputStream.read() != -1) {
                data = (NavigableMap) InputStream.readObject();
            } else {
                data = new TreeMap<>();
                System.out.println(data);
            }
            if (!data.isEmpty()) autoIncrement = data.lastKey();
            else autoIncrement = 0;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void closeAndWrite() {
        write();
        close();
    }

}
```

It is the `convertData(0` method that throws the exception. I have checked the file in question and it does indeed contain a serialized `Treemap`, which has been serialized using the `write()` method and also `close()` method. Now my question is where am I doing something wrong in either storing or retrieving the data?

Answer (score 0):

I'll get to where the error is but really your code makes no sense whatsoever and needs a thorough review:

```
public class FileDBMapApi {

    private FileOutputStream OutPutter;
    private FileInputStream Inputter;
```

You don't need the `FileInput/OutputStreams` separately as data members. Remove.

```
    // initialiserar databasen
    public void init() {
        // checkar om filen existerar och isåfall assignar inputter och outputter till filen
        System.out.println(currentFile.exists() && !currentFile.isDirectory());
        if (currentFile.exists() && !currentFile.isDirectory()) {
            try {
                OutPutter = new FileOutputStream(currentFile);
                OutPutter.flush();
                Inputter = new FileInputStream(currentFile);
                OutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(OutPutter);
                OutputStream.flush();
                InputStream = new ObjectInputStream(Inputter);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            // annars så skapar den filen och assignar det istället
            try {
                boolean temp1 = currentFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                boolean temp2 = currentFile.createNewFile();
                if (temp2) {
                    OutPutter = new FileOutputStream(currentFile);
                    Inputter = new FileInputStream(currentFile);
                    OutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(OutPutter);
                    InputStream = new ObjectInputStream(Inputter);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

You can reduce all that convoluted double-talk to this:

```
try {
    currentFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    OutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(currentFile));
    InputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(currentFile));
} catch (IOException exc) {
    exc.printStackTrace();
}
```

... although it would be better still if `init()` *threw* `IOException` rather than catching and absorbing it internally. All the complex code you wrote accomplishes exactly nothing more than this. And opening a file for output and input simultaneously really does not make sense, and doesn't work on some platforms such as Windows. You need to rethink this.

```
    public void write() {
        try {
            PrintWriter n = new PrintWriter(currentFile);
            n.close();
```

The problem is here. The `PrintWriter` is unused, so it should be removed, but the real problem here is that you have just truncated the output file, which is guaranteed to produce an `IOException` when reading it via an `ObjectInputStream`. Remove.

```
    public void close() {
        try {
            OutPutter.close();
            Inputter.close();
            InputStream.close();
            OutputStream.flush();
            OutputStream.close();
```

This is all nonsense. `flush()` before `close()` is redundant, and you only need to close `InputStream` and `OutputStream`. They will close their nested streams for you, and even if they didn't it makes no sense to close the nested output stream and *then* try to flush and close the outer output stream.

```
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Again the method should throw `IOException`, not absorb it.

```
    public long getFileSize() {
        return currentFile.length();
    }
```

This is pretty meaningless. On some operating systems such as Windows, the directory entry isn't updated until you close the file, so you could be just returning zero here. You shouldn't need to know the current length of the file.

```
        try {
            if (InputStream.read() != -1) {
```

This doesn't make any sense. Here you have read a byte and thrown it away. As you haven't written any extra bytes this can only put you out of synchronization with the stream. Remove this.

```
                data = (NavigableMap) InputStream.readObject();
            } else {
                data = new TreeMap<>();
                System.out.println(data);
            }
```

This 'else' doesn't make any sense either. If the file is empty or doesn't contain any more objects an `EOFException` is thrown, and it is there that you should take any evasive action. In fact, again, you should let the `IOExceptions` of all kinds be thrown here, instead of pointlessly substituting an empty `TreeMap`.

```
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

See above re throwing `IOException`. Don't write code like this.

```
    public void closeAndWrite() {
```

This method should be named `writeAndClose()`, if you really need it, which you don't.

> I have checked the file in question and it does indeed contain a serialized `Treemap`.

Checked it how? There's only one way to check that, and that's by calling `readObject()`.

Comment: Okey thank you so much for your harsh criticism! (No really thanks!) I have now changed the code like you suggested and i shall learn from my mistakes. (Still learning!) But when i try to run a test file with a write and then when i run it again it doesn't get the `Object`.. its just an empty `Treemap`. Now this would suggest that it threw an `EOFException`, but why does it do that if i have written to the file on a past run? Again thank you so much for the help and criticism!

Comment: Did you get an empty `TreeMap` *because of* an `EOFException`? If so, you still didn't serialize it, and NB you should not catch `EOFException` in that case and substitute a `new TreeMap()`: otherwise you can't tell what's going on. Just let the exception be thrown, as stated several times above, and let the caller deal with it. Otherwise did you perhaps serialize it when empty, fill it, then serialize it again? If so see `ObjectOutputStream.writeUnshared()` and `ObjectOutputStream.reset()`.

Comment: Yes I am doing as you said and catching the `Exception` and if it throws an `EOF` i make a `new TreeMap()`. i have to check out the methods you suggested thanks!

Comment: Okay so weird, I just tried to use `readObject()` after writing and it worked, i got the `TreeMap`. But when i run the program again it doesnt read the object and just creates an Empty `TreeMap`.

Comment: You are not doing as I said if you are catching `EOFException` *or* making a new `TreeMap`. You're just hiding problems from yourself. Don't write code like this.